# Travis CI and Multi-Language Projects

Tags: php, travis-ci

I am currently using travis for a Multi-Language Projects (PHP,JAVA,Nodejs).
But when i try to use php with travis i get this error :

```
sudo cp ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php-fpm.conf.default ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php-fpm.conf
/home/travis/build.sh: line 57: phpenv: command not found
```

I used this tutorial : https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php#Apache-%2B-PHP

Comment: Where's your `.travis.yml` file? A bit hard to help without seeing anything, right?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it does not look like this `sudo` is needed.